# Code sections and folding in Visual Studio with RTools

Tags: r, visual-studio-2017, rtvs

I am using VS 2017 with *R Tools for Visual Studio*, and I wonder if there is a way to create expandable code sections such as in RStudio:

```
#### My region ####
[...]
####           ####
```

I also tried `#region` and `#endregion`, which used to work with some others of the "Tools for Visual studio", but without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found out that to define a new code region, you must write a line that matches the following pattern (regex):  `^\s*#.*---\s*$`.

- Zero or more leading whitespace characters
- One hash `#`
- Any character, zero or more times
- Three hyphens `-` (and not 4 hyphens, hashs or equal signs like in RStudio)
- Zero or more trailing whitespace characters

By beginning another section, it will end the previous one and make it a block you can collapse.

---

So for instance you can make a new section like this:

```
# My section ---
    [...]
# ---
```

Comment: but how do you end the section?  Adding `# My section ---` to my code means *My section* goes to the end of my script.

Comment: By beginning another section, it will end the previous one and make it a block you can collapse, see the edit.